# Make a file hierarchy as a list of edges, then draw the tree structure as a graph

Tags: graph, julia

So I want to draw directory structures as tree graphs. I'm using [NetworkLayout.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/NetworkLayout.jl). I'm stuck on Step 1, but I can do Step 2 and Step 3.

1. Build a list of links between files and folders, to produce something like this (hand-made) one:

   ```
   links = Pair[
       "/"       => "System",
       "/"       => "Library",
       "/"       => "Users",
       "System"  => "sys1",
       "System"  => "sys2",
       "System"  => "sys3",
       "Library" => "lib1",
       "Library" => "lib2",
       "Library" => "lib3",
       "Users"   => "u1",
       "Users"   => "u2",
       "Users"   => "u3",
       "Users"   => "u4",
       "Users"   => "u5",
       "u5"      => "MyFolder"]
   ```
2. Create an adjacency list. This is easy enough if all the links are unique (also handmade):

   ```
   adjlist = [
   [2, 3, 4], 
   [5, 6, 7], 
   [8, 9, 10], 
   [], 
   [11], 
   [], 
   [], 
   [11, 12, 13, 14], 
   [], 
   [], 
   [15], 
   [], 
   [], 
   [], 
   []]
   ```
3. Make a layout. This is the easy bit, because NetworkLayout.jl does it all for you:

   ```
   using NetworkLayout
   NetworkLayout.Buchheim.layout(adjlist)
   ...>
   GeometryTypes.Point{2,Float64}[[0.0, -0.0], [-2.0, -2.0], [1.0, -2.0], 
   [2.0, -2.0], [-3.0, -4.0], [-2.0, -4.0], [-1.0, -4.0], [0.0, -4.0], 
   [1.0, -4.0], [2.0, -4.0], [-1.5, -6.0], [-0.5, -6.0], [0.5, -6.0], 
   [1.5, -6.0], [-1.5, -8.0]]
   ```

[image: graph plot]

So my question is, in Step 1, how to build the initial list of links between files. Some files may have identical names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  # get links with full path
    function read_sub_dirs(path::AbstractString)
      try # avoid access issue
        a = readdir(path)
        return a[isdir.((path*"/").*a)]
      catch
        return String[]
      end
    end
    function deepreaddir_raw(working_dir_path::AbstractString,search_depth::Int=2)
      links         = Array{Pair,1}()
      previous_dirs = [working_dir_path]
      for i in 1:search_depth
        if length(previous_dirs) > 0
          next_dirs   = String[]
          for each_dir in previous_dirs
            if each_dir[end] == '/'
              sub_dirs  = each_dir.*read_sub_dirs(each_dir)
            else
              sub_dirs  = (each_dir*"/").*read_sub_dirs(each_dir)
            end
            append!(links,each_dir.=>sub_dirs)
            append!(next_dirs,sub_dirs)
          end
          deleteat!(previous_dirs,1:length(previous_dirs))
          append!(previous_dirs,next_dirs)
        else
          break
        end
      end
      return links
    end

  # generate list of links
    function deepreaddir(working_dir_path::AbstractString,search_depth::Int=2)
      links_raw   = deepreaddir_raw(working_dir_path,2)
      links       = Pair[]
      for each_p in links_raw
        a = split(each_p[1],"/")[end];    b = split(each_p[2],"/")[end];
        a == "" ? a = working_dir_path : nothing
        push!(links,a=>b)
      end
      links
    end

  links   = deepreaddir(".")
```

```
# construct relationships
  tree_dic  = Dict{String,Array}()
  [tree_dic[x] = String[] for x in map(x->x[1],links)]
  for p in links
    push!(tree_dic[p[1]],p[2])
  end

# "System" ==> 1
  str2id_dic    = Dict{String,Int64}()
  [str2id_dic[links[i][2]] = i for i in 1:length(links)]

# loop through col2 of `links`, guess it's the output you want?
  str_res   = map(xx->haskey(tree_dic,xx) ? tree_dic[xx] : String[], map(x->x[2],links))

# to ids
  res       = [map(k->str2id_dic[k],x) for x in str_res]
```

```
julia> res       = [map(k->str2id_dic[k],x) for x in str_res]
15-element Array{Array{T,1} where T,1}:
 [4, 5, 6]           
 [7, 8, 9]           
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
 Any[]               
 Any[]               
 Any[]               
 Any[]               
 Any[]               
 Any[]               
 Any[]               
 Any[]               
 Any[]               
 Any[]               
 [15]                
 Any[]
```

Comment: Thanks, looks useful code - my main problem, though, is how to create the `links` from the file system (step 1).

Answer (score 1):

I’m biased here, but why not use MetaGraphs.jl instead of rolling your own graph structure? Also, for files with the same name, a combination of file system ID and inode should be globally unique at a given point in time.

I would create the Metagraph and populate it with output from stat: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.stat

Comment: I'm not sure that helps with Step 1 - although once the files have been organized into a tree with unique IDs perhaps it would become useful...

Comment: it might be too complicated if you want to assume that fully-rooted paths are globally unique (that is, `/foo/bar/baz` is unique). In that case, you could use [walkdir](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.walkdir) and use the rooted path as the vertex. When you want to extract just the path or the name, all you need to do is use [dirname](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.dirname) or [basename](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.basename) from the vertex info and you should be all set.